# Force UEFI Issue for Installing Ubuntu 16.04 on Lenovo Legion Y730 - Windows 10

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, system-installation, uefi, lenovo

I am experiencing quite a few issues trying to install Ubuntu 16.04 LTS as a dual boot option on my Lenovo Legion Y730 laptop. It is my first time going through with an Ubuntu install so I've been visiting many forums trying to get this working, but I have finally hit a spot where I haven't been able to find a solution. I have not been having any issues connecting to WiFi.

The main issue I am currently experiencing is when I am going through with the installation setup and it gives you the option to:

1. Download updates while installing Ubuntu.
2. Install third-party software for graphics and WiFi hardware, flash, MP3 and other media.

I noticed that my installion would freeze if I included the second option so I have been proceeding from this step by selecting only the first option. Once I press "Continue", I receive the following error:

*Force UEFI Installation?
This machine's firmware has started the installer in UEFI mode but it looks like there may be existing operating systems already installed using "BIOS compatibility mode". If you continue to install Debian in UEFI mode, it might be difficult to reboot the machine into any BIOS-mode operating systems later.*

*If you wish to install in UEFI mode and don't care about keeping the ability to boot one of the existing systems, you have the option to force that here. If you wish to keep the option to boot an existing operating system, you should choose NOT to force UEFI installation here.*

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VVgt.jpg)

The issue I am having is that I my system IS currently in UEFI mode and I am trying to install in UEFI mode, so I am not sure where this error is coming from. I have seen this error on other forum posts and the solution always has to do with ensuring that the BIOS mode is the same as the bootable drive mode.

[Laptop BIOS Mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwO3u.jpg)

I have also ensured that that my BIOS mode is set to UEFI in the UEFI settings. I have disabled secure boot and fast boot.

I am using RUFUS 3.3 to create the bootable USB drive with a `GPT partition scheme` and an `UEFI only` target system (as my laptop is UEFI). I have also tried an `MBR partition scheme` with a `BIOS (or UEFI-CSM)` Target system. Finally, I have ensured that the Ubuntu 16.04 iso image is not corrupted.

I have no idea why the error above is appearing and would appreciate any help or insight that can be provided.

Comment: This is an Ubuntu forum, and Debian is somewhat different. But it is saying you have another installed system using BIOS boot. Installing in UEFI mode will probably erase that system by  converting drive from MBR to gpt.

Comment: I am installing Ubuntu 16.04. My understanding is Ubuntu is based on Debian? This image was downloaded from the official Ubuntu releases website. My understanding is that this Ubuntu forum is for questions related to Ubuntu?

I currently have Windows 10 installed in UEFI mode and I am trying to install Ubuntu in UEFI mode as a dual boot option. My question is in relation to the error I am receiving. Is there another location I should be posting this in?

Comment: This: https://unix.stackexchange.com/ or Ubuntu forums has a sub-forum for Debian: https://ubuntuforums.org/forumdisplay.php?f=161